# MultiValueDictKeyError at /app/upload　"'file'"

Tags: python

MultiValueDictKeyError at /app/upload　"'file'"　error happens.

I wrote

```
import os
import shutil
def upload(request):
    file = request.FILES['file'].temporary_file_path()

　　with open(file, 'rb') as f:
         file_content = f.read()

　　with open("test.wav", 'wb') as f:
       f.write(file_content)
       f.close() 
       shutil.move("test.wav", "/Users/xxx/Downloads/test.wav")
```

and I set Key file & Value the wav file in POSTMAN like
[image]

and I run this code,the error happens.I do not know why this error happens because I think this error happens when I use html in wrong way `<form action="" method="post">`

In this case,`enctype="multipart/form-data"` is no there,so MultiValueDictKeyError happens.But now I send data via POSTMAN so I really cannot understand why this error happens.How should I fix this?

Comment: You don't need `f.close()`. Move the `shutil` call outside the `with` block.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I did so,but same error happens.How should I fix this?